# github autogenerated comments

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I recently tried to revert my local github branch to an earlier version through the github desktop app. It gave me the error

```
error: revert is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: revert failed
 (128)
```

and then when I opened up my project in Eclipse, I got comments such as

```
<<<<<<< HEAD

and

=======
>>>>>>> parent of [something]... Merge branch 'master' into robertsBranch
```

And these are causing all sorts of syntax errors. How do I undo this and just go back to a previous version of my branch without these error generating comments, and without error messages. Is it possible to just go back in time with github branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I undo this and just go back to a previous version of my branch without these error generating comments, and without error messages.

These aren't comments. They're [merge conflict indicators](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_configuration), showing where merge conflicts exist.

> Is it possible to just go back in time with github branches?

As shown in the error message you received, these conflicts arose when you tried to merge `master` into `robertsBranch`. You have to decide whether that merge is important (in which case you must [manually resolve the conflicts](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merge-Conflicts)) or not (in which case you can [abort the merge](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#_abort_merge) and proceed with your `revert`).